# Походження слова "кульчики"

Tags: етимологія

Бабуся завжди казала на сережки - кульчики. Я була здивована, що в  СУМ - 20 є стаття про це слово.

[Кульчик](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=45979&page=1453) а, ч., діал. Сережка

Цікавить, як виникло це слово (походження).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ЕСУМ каже, що це запозичення з польської мови:

[image]

пор. - порівняй | ч. - чеська | п. - польська | ст. - старе | тс. - те саме